# Django use calculated field for ordering_fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, calculated-field

I'm using Django and Django Rest Framework, with PostgreSQL. I need to create a calculated field on the model, and I need to also order by the field.
I thought of using `@property` decorator for the calculated field, but as far as I know, I can't add this 'field' to the `ordering_fields` array. My question is - what would be the right way to do it?

Should be something like (partial):

The model-

```
class MyModelViewSet(models.Model):
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    final_due_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def due_date_diff(self):
        if self.final_due_date:
            return self.final_due_date - due_date
        else:
            return due_date - date.today()
```

In the View I would like to do something like:

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    ordering_fields = tuple(serializer_class.Meta.fields + due_date_diff)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do an ordering on a property like this, but you could [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) your QuerySet, like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    date_diff = ExpressionWrapper(F('final_due_date') - F('due_date'), 
                    output_field=fields.DurationField())

    return super(MyModelViewSet, self).get_queryset().annotate(due_date_diff = date_diff)
```

You can then order your QuerySet on that annotation.